# PLSQL Procedure to load data into dimension table from multiple tables

Tags: plsql, loading, dimension

I have a requirement to load distinct costcenternum and a seq_key to be inserted. I wrote a procedure but this is failing one is distinct and even after removing distinct not able to run this procedure.

Please help me to correct this query to generate a seq key and also distinct cost numbers into the division table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE POPULATE_DIVISION_DIM AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DIVISION(
"COST_CENTER_KEY"
,"COST_CENTER_NUM"
,"COST_CENTER_DESC"
,"DIVISION_CODE"
,"DIVISION_DESC"
,"COMPANY_CODE"
,"INSERT_DT"
,"UPDATE_DT"
 ) 
(
 SELECT
    cc_sequence.nextval cost_center_key
    , distinct (pcaf.segment4) costcenter_num 
    ,ffvv.description costcenter_desc
    ,hoi.org_information9 division
    ,(SELECT description
                       FROM hr_lookups
                       WHERE lookup_type = 'CAT'
                       AND lookup_code = hoi.org_information9) 
         division_desc
    , ppg.segment1 company
    ,TRUNC(SYSDATE) insert_dt
    ,TRUNC(SYSDATE) update_dt
      FROM  
   hr_organization_information hoi
 , hr_all_organization_units haou
 , pay_cost_allocation_keyflex pcaf
 , fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv
 , per_all_assignments_f paaf
 , pay_people_groups ppg
 WHERE 1=1 
    AND paaf.people_group_id = ppg.people_group_id
    AND haou.cost_allocation_keyflex_id = 
     pcaf.cost_allocation_keyflex_id(+)
    AND pcaf.segment4 = ffvv.flex_value(+)
    AND (ffvv.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID is null or ffvv.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID=
           (SELECT FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID FROM FND_FLEX_VALUE_SETS WHERE 
       FLEX_VALUE_SET_NAME = 'ABCD'))
    AND ffvv.enabled_flag(+) = 'Y'
    AND haou.organization_id = hoi.organization_id
    AND hoi.org_information_context = 'XX'
      )
  ;

   COMMIT;
    END POPULATE_DIVISION_DIM;
```

Comment: My cost center num is unique by division and company code. for e.g; I have to insert data like below. key cc number cc desc division divsion_desc company 1 100 IT professionals IT ITExec abc    2 100 IT1 IT123 cde like this

Comment: As you can see, posting info (you posted as a comment) is difficult to read. You should have posted it as part of the question and format it properly. To me, it is unclear what you want to do. "Unique" value can easily be produced by a **sequence** (such as you're using for COST_CENTER_KEY). Note that `distinct pcaf.segment4` won't produce distinct values for `pcaf.segment4` only, but the whole SELECT column list; obviously, if using `distinct` creates duplicates, removing it will produce that much (or even more) duplicate values, so that certainly isn't the solution.

Comment: *"not able to run this procedure."* Please post the error message you get. We don't have your table structures nor data, so we can't compile and run your code. Consequently we can have **no idea** why your procedure is failing. We only know what you tell us. So, help us to help you.

Comment: As mentioned by littlefoot above the distinct works across the whole select so must be directly after your select. You  have it after your first column this will cause an error.  Don't know your data ect but you could try moving it to the start of your select and removing the brackets as they are redundant (although will not cause an error).

Comment: My cost center num is unique by division and company code. 
for e.g; I have to insert data like below. 
KEY CC_NUMBER CC_DESC DIVISION DIVISION_DESC COMPANY
1 100                 IT PROFES IT               ITEXEC                 abc
2 100            IT1                 IT123       ITSTAFF                 cde       For each Cost Center Num, I have multiple divisions. I want to get distinct Costcenter num, with division and populate this cost_center_key as well. When I run this query, 16/9 PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression (at cc_sequence.nextval line)
Errors: check compiler log;

Comment: If I Remove the(cc_sequence.nextval ) and Cost_center_key column from Insert column list  , The procedure is compiled successfully but no data was loaded into DIVISION table.  Please help to fix the code to populate data